# Getting selected text from path in python

Tags: python

My variable has name like this:

```
var1 = '/home/name/file.txt'
```

How to just get name of file in variable?

I need my variable like this:

```
var1 = 'file.txt'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.basename('/home/name/file.txt')
'file.txt'
```